# Find last year fiscal year data with calendar table SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

My database has a calendar table that provides the fiscal year, period, etc. based on date (using Teradata with SQLAssistant). I'm trying to get last year's data in a SQL query which I thought would be as simple as adding a -1 in the where clause but it isn't working. I don't want to hard code a date in as I don't want to remember to update the query when the fiscal year changes.

Simplified query that works and brings back sales data for all fiscal years:

```
Select s.sales, c.fiscalPeriod, c.fiscalYear
from sales s
join calendar c
on s.salesDate = c.calDate
```

What I've tried, but it's bringing back no data:

```
Select s.sales, c.fiscalPeriod, c.fiscalYear
from sales s
join calendar c
on s.salesDate = c.calDate
where c.fiscalYear=c.fiscalYear-1
```

And this:

```
Select s.sales, c.fiscalPeriod, c.fiscalYear, c.fiscalYear-1 AS lastYear
from sales s
join calendar c
on s.salesDate = c.calDate
where c.fiscalYear=lastYear
```

As is probably obvious, I'm fairly new to SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Teradata but what you need is the function the returns current date. Comparing the column to itself makes no sense.

Comment: Our fiscal year isn't based on a calendar year(it's March-Feb) so if I pull the current date and subtract one year to set as the fiscal year it won't be accurate part of the time. Or were you suggesting to use the current date some other way?

Comment: Ok. You still need current date. Use that to get current month to determine fiscal year. Example: `year(current date) - case when month(current date) between 1 and 9 then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get last years fiscal data then probably the best way should be to set the fiscalyear as a constant in the where clause.

For example:

```
to_char(fiscalYear,'yyyy')='2015'
```

There are many date altering fuctions, search for them, they are handy.

Comment: I didn't want to hard code a year in there so I didn't have to update it later. I will update my initial question to reflect that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your financial year starts in march subtract two months from today and then use `TRUNC` to find Jan 1st of that year:

```
trunc(add_months(calendar_date,-2), 'y')
```

And then apply `add_months`:

```
Select s.sales, c.fiscalPeriod, c.fiscalYear
from sales s
join calendar c
on s.salesDate = c.calDate
where c.calDate between add_months(trunc(add_months(current_date,-2), 'y'), -10)
                    and add_months(trunc(add_months(current_date,-2), 'y'), 2)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I haven't misunderstood your question, but, if the **calendar** table is filled up to the current date, you could use this query.

```
  Select s.sales, c_lastyear.fiscalPeriod, c_lastyear.fiscalYear
    from sales s
         join calendar c_lastyear
           on s.salesDate = c_lastyear.calDate
         join calendar c
           on c_lastyear.fiscalYear=c.fiscalYear-1
   where c.calDate= current_date
```

The steps are:

1. find the current fiscal year by accessing the calendar table with the
   current date (the alias **c**)
2. get all the dates of the previous fiscal year (the alias
   **c_lastyear**)
3. get all the sales of the previous fiscal year (the alias **s**)

(the performance won't be as good as the other proposals, but this query doesn't make assumptions on the actual definition of your fiscal year)